# Phonegap FileTransfer to send without content disposition, name, filename, and content type

Tags: cordova

**--+++++**

**Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="new.xml"**

**Content-Type: application/xml****

**xml content here** *-- this is all I want*

**--+++++--**      *This line on the bottom / tail end of the xml*

When i look at the xml file on the android device it does not contain this information it only holds the xml data.

Im trying to figure out how to send an xml to the server without the above getting attached to the document. The server will only process xml posts without all of the extra information on it.

Here is my function:

```
 function uploadPhoto(xml) {


var url = 'myurl';
// retrieve the cookie from login
var userId = localStorage.getItem("user");
var password = localStorage.getItem("pass");
var authorizationToken = "Basic " + userId + ":" + password;
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.mimeType="application/xml";
var params = new Object();

var isiDevice = /ipad|iphone|ipod/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
// test for android device
var isAndroid = /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
// retrieve the cookie from login
if (isiDevice)
{
    params.chunkedMode = true;
    params.fileName = "order.xml";
    options.headers = {'Authorization': authorizationToken}; 
    options.params = params;
} 
else if (isAndroid)
{  
    params.headers={'AUTHORIZATION': authorizationToken};
    params.chunkedMode = true;
    params.fileName = "order.xml";
    options.params = params;
}


    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(xml, url, win, fail, options);
}
```

Thanks for any help ill post back if I find an answer before I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

i had a code like much like this,on receiving end i received into byte[] and print it..
that time i got it print in a format how you expected.. try it and check